# Rails: image_tag issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, scope, carrierwave

I can't figure out why this don't work. I have events in my index page and I want to show three of them with an image and the title, so

In my Event model:

```
  scope :host_admin, where(hoster_type: "Admin").order("start_time DESC").limit(3)
```

In the index page:

```
<% Event.host_admin.each do |event| %>
  <%= image_tag(event.image(:home)) %>
  <p class="evento"><%= event.title %>
    <%= link_to "read_all", event_path %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and in the carierwave uploader simmply:

```
version :home do
  process :resize_to_fit => [90, 60]
end
```

**The error is:
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)**

And this is the problem because if I try to replace

```
      <%= image_tag(event.image(:home)) %>
```

with this

```
      <%= image_tag event.image %>
```

it works, but I need the image to be resized?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are passing :home to the image object, and not to the url method. You need to change your image tag to:

```
<%= image_tag(event.image_url(:home)) %>
```

Comment: He said he is using carrierwave, not paperclip

Comment: @Faisal Thanks, just retagged it.