# carrierwave :thumb wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm following along with Ryan Bates' carrierwave Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads. At one point, after resizing the images into a thumbnail, he displays the thumbnail with the following code

```
  <%=  image_tag painting.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

I'm calling the url method on the profilepic instance variable and trying to get the thumbnail like this

```
 <%=  image_tag @profilepic.url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

But I get the error

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

It's not expecting the :thumb parameter.

In the image_uploader, I arranged for the thumbnail to be created like this (after installing rmagick)

```
 version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  end
```

Can anyone explain what I might be doing wrong? I found an SO question on topic [Rails: image_tag issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600095/rails-image-tag-issue), which explains that the parameter (in this case :thumb) needs to be passed to the url method on the object (and not the object itself). That's what I'm doing, but I'm getting the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, the code from Ryan have a typo

```
<%=  image_tag painting.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

the correct one is

```
<%=  image_tag painting.image.url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

This already posted in the comment of that esp.

For your code, the @profilepic is a obj from model or from carrierwave

e.g. @profilepic = ProfilePic.find :first
@profilepic.url is just a method from ProfilePic

The correct syntax for call the url of carrierwave control file is 
@profilepic.image.url(:thumb)

Hope this not too confusing.