# Upload with CarrierWave is resulting in "no such file" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I just started playing with [CarrierWave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) and am having trouble getting it to behave.

After setting everything up as described in [Rails Casts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads), I am getting the following error: `No such file or directory - identify -quiet -ping /tmp/mini_magick20130519-13712-lxhans.jpg` 
*NOTE: I am aware of the [typo in that Rails Cast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16228848/866618) and that issue does not exist in my code.*

In my dev environment, I've installed the `libmagickwand-dev` package, running `Rails 3.2.9`, and `Ruby 1.9.3p194`, among other things. My Gemfile includes `mini_magick`.

The request being passed to the server is this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"8ugcdkjOy/5yeodhuTgMXYdrXlcu2xPjxWTvvRwKnWM=",
 "organization"=>{"logo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x0000000426c3d0 @original_filename="leather-tshirt-weird-square.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"organization[logo]\"; filename=\"leather-tshirt-weird-square.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
 @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20130519-13712-1uvmtem>>,
 "name"=>"Test Org",
 "description"=>"blah",
 "timezone"=>"1"},
 "commit"=>"Create Organization"}
```

The full trace is located here: http://pastebin.com/dW5j9NLt

After initially trying some more advanced functionality, I dumbed the code down to the following and am still having no luck:

```
class LogoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [100, 100]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

EDIT: I have narrowed the issue down to something with modifying the image after upload. If I simplify the code even farther to remove the creation of the `:thumb` size then everything works. Thoughts?

Comment: Is this problem specific to one file or one format? Do you know if any temp image is being created when mini magick is being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you explicitly installed ImageMagick?

I had the same error when using MiniMagick without installing ImageMagick. As I understand it MiniMagick defers operations to the mogrify command, so if you can't call mogrify on the command line, MiniMagick probably can't either.

A *nix buff would be able to answer this with more confidence, but I think libmagickwand-dev supports the installation of graphics libraries, but doesn't actually install any itself.

Answer (score 6):

Not enough reputation to comment theflyingbrush's answer, but he is absolutely right.
I had the same issue before noticing that I was actually missing imagemagick all together.

So on Debian/Ubuntu this will do the trick (or 'magick'):

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

On operating systems with yum as packet manager (CentOS/RedHat) you'd be using:

```
yum install ImageMagick
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing storage location. Try adding this under storage :file

```
  def store_dir
    "uploads/logo/#{model.id}"
  end
```